# How to search an old post in a Facebook page with hundreds of posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, search

I want to view a very old post in a Facebook page, e.g. this [page](https://www.facebook.com/TimHieuVeChienTranhVietNamVietNamWar), which contains hundreds to thousands of posts.

Browsing manually through the post stack of the page is so tiring and seems to be impossible for me to find that post.

How can I do a search for it like we do with a Google search?

I know we can search for our own posts via *Activity Log*, though for a Facebook page owned by others, what can we do?

Comment: @pnuts And you can only find on those posts that are currently loaded. How about the unloaded posts e.g. lie in the next deep deep down below?

Comment: Have you tried using the Facebook API?

Comment: @barrycarter Not yet. Please tell us more.

Answer (score 1):

This will soon be possible from the native Facebook search, if only for english at the moment. See [the official announcement](http://newsroom.fb.com/news/2014/12/updates-to-facebook-search/) for more info. Also, see how it works [here](http://search.fb.com).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use this tool to search for old post
[Search for old facebook post](http://findfb.net/Search-Post.aspx)

Comment: Please disclose if you are affiliated with the software in any way.

Comment: That was a great tool, but unfortunately it stopped working.. any other similar alternatives?